# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR error when opening a website using playwright in nestjs

Tags: web-scraping, nestjs, web-crawler, playwright

`Error: page.goto: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR at https://example.com`

```
const browser = await chromium.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ['--disable-web-security'],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com')
```

nestjs: 10.0.4
playwright: 1.36.2

I tried retrying the opening action when the opening failed but it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this for your config: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-ignore-https-errors